# Could not pass value from ajax.beginform to controller's method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

**View:**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditP", "P",new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divReplace" }))
{     
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Req,new {@id="req"});   
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult EditP(long requestSequence,FormCollection form)
{  
    ...........
}
```

I can see `Model.req` value as 234, but when it reaches controller shows it as 0.

Atleast when I use `form.Get("req")` to collect the value, This too shows it as 0.

Kindly, help.

Comment: To improve formatting, instead of using " \` ", try adding four spaces before `[HttpPost]` and before the function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you just changed your controller code to be:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult EditSCP(long Req,FormCollection form)
{  
    ...........
}
```

Then the variable Req would have the value you want in it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Infact, my model is in this way:

`public partial class MyModel : Request
 {
       public long id{get; set;}
 }`

where as 'Request' Model has the Req property in it. Lazy loading is creating a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, some problem with model here, your model should have `get;` & `set;` like this...

```
public class MyModel
{
 public long Req {get; set;}    
}
```

Comment: Infact, my model is in this way:

`public partial class MyModel : Request
 {
       public long id{get; set;}
 }`

where as 'Request' Model has the Req property in it. Lazy loading is creating a problem.